# Get Or Reading Data Taxonomy Term Store Sharepoint

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, taxonomy, sharepointframework

I create web part with share point framework "no JavaScript framework" my code with TypeScript I have problem, I will get, or reading data taxonomy term store share point.

And my code in image [image]

Question: how to declare variable "SP" in my code? Because my code error asking variable "SP" to declare first

Comment: Welcome to stack ! Don't use a screenshot to show your code, include it in your post as text, this way people can easily read it, and copy it to try it out.

Comment: i am sorry, because my first question in stackoverflow..

Comment: Don't worry, just keep that in mind for your next posts :)

Comment: Noted for my next posts, thank you very much to reminder me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SP is part of sp.js,but as you are working with SPFX WebPart, you should use TypeScript instead, please check the demo to read Taxonomy in SPFX webpart:

[Taxonomy Web Part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/dev/samples/knockout-taxonomy)

And this file shows get Term from Term Store using TypeScript:

[sp-dev-fx-webparts/samples/knockout-taxonomy/src/webparts/termSetRequester/data-helpers/DataHelperSP.ts](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/dev/samples/knockout-taxonomy/src/webparts/termSetRequester/data-helpers/DataHelperSP.ts)

Comment: Thank you very much, i have success reading data taxonomy with your solution.

Comment: Now i must filter data taxonomy by parent id. sorry any reference to it ?

Comment: this is not working on Internet explorer edge while working on chrome and firefox , any one faced similar issue , pointers?